# Unable to step over/step into in Eclipse pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm currently having a trouble with Eclipse and pydev. I have set this in my code :

```
import pydevd;pydevd.settrace();
```

And I have my debug server up and running.

When I run my application, I can see it stopped running since I setup remote debugger there. However when I switch back to eclipse, I'm unable to click step over or step into button. It is currently disabled.

I have increased the log level in pydev and based on the log, it seems it can connect to the debug server successfully :

```
2015-11-03T14:04:22+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] ('Connecting to ', '127.0.0.1', ':', '5678')
2015-11-03T14:04:22+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] ('Connected.',)
2015-11-03T14:04:23+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] Received command: CMD_VERSION 501  1   1.1 UNIX    ID
2015-11-03T14:04:23+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] Received command: CMD_SET_PY_EXCEPTION 131 3   false;false;false;true;
2015-11-03T14:04:23+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] Received command: CMD_SET_PROPERTY_TRACE 133   5   
2015-11-03T14:04:24+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] Received command: CMD_IGNORE_THROWN_EXCEPTION_AT 140   7   REPLACE:
2015-11-03T14:04:24+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] Received command: CMD_REMOVE_DJANGO_EXCEPTION_BREAK 126    9   DjangoExceptionBreak
2015-11-03T14:04:24+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] Received command: CMD_ENABLE_DONT_TRACE 141    11  true
2015-11-03T14:04:24+08:00 sawebserver-uwsgi@127.0.0.1 [info] Received command: CMD_RUN 101  13
```

I performed netstat and the port seems to be available :

```
tcp6       0      0 :::5678                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Is there anything that I have missed?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of eclipse in this state, there may be some clues there.

Comment: This is the state which it manage to connect to debugger [link](http://s16.postimg.org/fcm2oplsl/state.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your selection away from and back to the stack frame.

Comment: I tried this but still no luck.. the button are still disabled.